# How to calculate probability of more than some percent value?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

For example, suppose the probability that an article pass the acceptance test of a company in a given day is $0.55$. What is the probability that one day they accept more than $75%$ of the articles?

I have no idea of how to "attack" it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Without more information such as the distribution of the acceptance you can not work it out.

Comment: You need to know how many articles are reviewed each day.  You are probably expected to assume that each article is accepted independently f all the others.  Once you have the number of articles reviewed, you have a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information on the distribution of various quantities, one cannot give an exact method with the information you give.
Here is an approximation to the computation.
I'll interprete the statement "the probability that an article pass the acceptance test of a company in a given day is 0.55" as meaning the item production and inspection process are such that any item inspected has probability 0.55 of being accepted, or that on any given day the probability of acceptant is 0.55 + (deviation) where the deviation has such sall variance that it can be neglected.

Let N = number of items inspected (on a given day),
and let X = number of items accepted (on the same day).
Then my interpretation of the 0.55 statement translates to:
X ~ Binomial( N, p=0.55)
so
$ P( \frac{X}{N} \ge 0.75 ) = 
P( \frac{X/N - .55}{\sqrt \frac{p(1-p)}{N}} \ge  
\frac{.75 - .55}{\sqrt \frac{p(1-p)}{N}} )$.
If $X$ and $N - X$ are larger than 5, then the distribution of 
$ z = \frac{X/N - p}{\sqrt \frac{p(1-p)}{N}} $
is approximately normal, so
$ P( z \ge \frac{.75 - p}{\sqrt \frac{p(1-p)}{N}}) \approx 1 - \Phi(\frac{.75 - .55}{\sqrt \frac{p(1-p)}{N}})$
where $\Phi$ is the cummulative distribution function of the standard normal distributio.

If $N$ is not know, as a first approximation, it can be repaced by an average number of items inspected (again, assuming that the number does not vary too much).

Ths is a start. There are simple improvements to the above approximation that are easy to implemnt, e.g. "continuity correction."